# When I connect to PartialView to Main Layout i can get an error

Tags: model-view-controller

I am using MVC5  when I connect to ParcelView to Main Layout i can get an error

Additional information: The partialview '~/login/Login/_SideMenus' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched

@Html.Partial("~/login/Login/_SideMenus")

Answer (score 0):

When you add partial view to main layout then each and every view to send data of partial view. It is every time render partial view of main layout. So may be model of partial view not passing to given error.